# How is it possible to use 'auth.navbar' for custom navigations?

Tags: python, web2py

I was searching for ways to customize my navigation like NOT puting User-related Links into a dropdown.

How is it possible to use `auth.navbar` to create custom navigations?

I found this in the [documents](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/05/the-views?search=auth.navbar):
*The {{=auth.navbar(...)}} displays a welcome to the current user and links to the auth functions like login, logout, register, change password, etc. depending on context. It is a helper factory and its output can be manipulated as any other helper.*

**EDIT:**
I simply want to change the way the Auth-Menu is rendered. Right now it is rendered as a dropdown menu. I figured out that `auth.navbar(mode="dropdown")` does this. Removing `mode="dropdown"` alters the ouput to a simple SPAN.

Or the other way round - where could i change the method providing the output?

EDIT 2:
For the moment I did this - but i think it is not the most elegant way:

```
{{for i in range(0, len(auth.navbar().elements()[0])):}}
    {{if i in [2, 4, 6, 8]:}} # Get rid of "[,],|"
        {{next}}
    {{else:}}
    <li>{{=auth.navbar().elements()[0][i]}}</li>
    {{pass}}
{{pass}}
```

Comment: Can you provide more detail regarding what you want to do? `auth.navbar` takes a number of arguments allowing you to customize it. Furthermore, it returns a web2py HTML helper object that can be further manipulated as described [here](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/05/the-views#Server-side-DOM-and-parsing).

Comment: Thanks Anthony. I played around with it and came up with a solution. Please see edit above,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [`auth.navbar` signature](http://web2py.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tools.html#gluon.tools.Auth.navbar). What you want can be achieved with this:

```
{{=auth.navbar(separators=('', '', ''))}}
```

You can also call `auth.navbar(mode='bare')`, which will return a dictionary with the relevant URLs and labels. You can then pass that dictionary to a custom navbar function to lay out and style the navbar as you like. For more details, see the [docstring](https://github.com/web2py/web2py/blob/master/gluon/tools.py#L1557).

Comment: Wow, thanks! A short answer going deep. The solution provides in the docstring fits perfect!